# Eclipse CDT displays semantic error, but builds successfully

Tags: c++, g++, eclipse-cdt

Before I update g++ from 4.6 to 4.7, my eclipse indigo CDT ran normally. After updating, it displays semantic errors, but builds and runs successfully. My code is that

```
using my_type = int;
```

Eclipse displays warning "syntax error"

I updated g++ 4.7 as default compiler.

Comment: This is a bug. I faced it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by updating to eclipse juno . Before, I used eclipse helois what only supports C/C++ development tool 7.0